# Leaflet Marker not found production env

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet, erb

I got a problem with leaflet.

Everything is working fine in development, but in production, my app isn't able to locate the `marker-icon.png` and `marker-shadow.png` images.

It is looking for the path `assets/station/images/marker-icon.png`

Leaflet js is including like this in my html.erb file

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.5/leaflet.css" />
```

If someone can help!

Comment: Which version of Leaflet? How do you deploy the Leaflet JS and CSS files? Where do those files come from (framework, manual download, etc)?

Comment: I've edit my post!

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 57):

This is a known bug in Leaflet, the root issue is that Leaflet's icon image location is been wrongly referenced during bundling. 
You can verify that this is your issue, buy validating this parameter (in run time): `L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl()`.
The correct value should be `<some_directory>/leaflet/dist/images/`. 
However if this bug is happening to you, it's value is: `data:image/png;base64,iVBO....K5CYII=")undefined`

There are different solutions (work around) depending on which bundle-loader you are using (Vanila WebPack, Angular-Cli - superset of WebPack, etc...).

You can see the original issue here (as well as different solutions depending on your bandle-loader): 
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968

If you are using Angular-Cli this solution will work for you.
Add this code somewhere before setting the Maker:

```
import { icon, Marker } from 'leaflet';
const iconRetinaUrl = 'assets/marker-icon-2x.png';
const iconUrl = 'assets/marker-icon.png';
const shadowUrl = 'assets/marker-shadow.png';
const iconDefault = icon({
  iconRetinaUrl,
  iconUrl,
  shadowUrl,
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
  shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
Marker.prototype.options.icon = iconDefault;
```

(this code will change the broken Marker's url, to a valid image from your assets folder).

And add this code at you angular.json (for Angular version >= 6.x) or at your angular-cli.json (for Angular version <= 5.x):

```
"assets":
[
   "src/favicon.ico",
   "src/assets",
   {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/", // you may need to change this path, according to your files structure
      "output": "./assets/"
   }
] ...
```

(this code will copy the original Marker images to the `/assets` folder so angular-cli could load them)

Comment: While this could be a nice explanation for Angular, notice that OP never mentioned using a JS bundler, their incorrect path is not a data URI, and includes old (0.x) Leaflet assets from CDN.

Comment: This fix works for a vite (rollup) & vue3 build. Go into `node_modules/leaflet/dist/images` and pluck those three marker png files. Stick them in `public/assets` and build away.

Comment: Should have been the accepted answer. This works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

```
import "leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png";
```

if using webpack, just import the image

Comment: Are you sure this is offering anything new that the other answers are not already offering?

Comment: Is it a nice one-line fix.

Comment: This solution is simple, and will fix with all angular versions, fantastic

Comment: Awesome. This fixed my issue. I am using ngx-leaflet. Thanks!

Comment: I concur with user43284 - Lesser code that is simpler is in my opinion better and cleaner.
I can confirm this worked for Angular10

Answer (score 24):

Below code worked for me

```
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png"),
  iconUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"),
  shadowUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png")
});
```

Comment: got error with above code snippet. Error: "TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig"

Comment: I'm not clear, where are you saying to add this bit of code to?

Comment: @NashGC can you elaborate on how you did this with Nuxt? I'm importing leaflet locally into one single component instead of using a plugin, where did you place this block of code?

Comment: @Thorvald, I've used it in mounted() method of a map component. (component where I use map)

Comment: @NashGC This does work for me.. however my marker disappears in Safari browsers. Any idea how this would be fixed? I'm on leaflet 1.7.1, vue2-leaflet 2.7.0

Comment: getting error `Property '_getIconUrl' does not exist on type 'Default'` Using create-react-app with TypeScript

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me too ... but without the require function.  I just added iconUrl: "/webroot/assets/js/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png", and so on ... of course fitting to my base url.

Answer (score 8):

> Working in Angular 10

For me worked copy paste PNGs files to assets and one command

`ngOnInit() { L.Icon.Default.ImagePath = "assets/leaflet/" }`

For Angular 13 with Leaflet 1.7

`ngOnInit() { L.Icon.Default.imagePath = "assets/leaflet/" }`

Answer (score 3):

You can change the current path of the icon in leaflet css.
So don't use the url leaflet.css, download the file and change it.

```
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
    background-image: url(https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked exactly as I needed and is a very clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

For Vue3 with typescript and vue-cli + Webpack 5,
I use a workaround by explicitly defining the required icons in created() hook.

```js
    created() {
        L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = L.icon({
            iconRetinaUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png"),
            iconUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"),
            shadowUrl: require("leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"),
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
            shadowSize: [41, 41],
        });
    },
```

After that I create my map in the mounted() hook:

```
    mounted() {
        const map:L.Map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: process.env.VUE_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN
        }).addTo(map);
    }
```

note: I store my Mapbox in a VUE_APP_ prefixed env variable.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by downloading `marker-icon.png` and `marker-shadow.png` from https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png and https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png respectively and deployed them as image assets to the  "`/`" route of my web app.

Comment: https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-icon-2x.png 
https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-shadow.png

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me with Laravela and Vite configured project
**Override Leaflet's default icon paths:**

Leaflet allows you to change the default paths for icons. You can override the default icon path after you have ensured that the images are in your *dist* folder:

```
import markerIcon2x from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png';
import markerIcon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import markerShadow from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png';

delete leaFlet.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

leaFlet.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon2x,
  iconUrl: markerIcon,
  shadowUrl: markerShadow
});
```

I have used this solution in our [Laravel Admin Template](https://themeselection.com/item/category/laravel-admin-templates/) where we use leaflat and it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue using `Parcel` as the bundler in combination with `TypeScript` and `Leaflet v1.4` (installed via `npm`, as well as its typings) and solved it using Gil's answer in a slightly different way.

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css';
import L, {
  LatLngExpression,
  FeatureGroup,
  TileLayerOptions,
  LayerEvent,
  LeafletMouseEvent,
  Marker,
  Layer,
  icon,
  LayerGroup,
  GeoJSON
} from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-draw';
import iconRetinaUrl from './assets/marker-icon-2x.png';
import iconUrl from './assets/marker-icon.png';
import shadowUrl from './assets/marker-shadow.png';

// Assign the imported image assets before you do anything with Leaflet.
Marker.prototype.options.icon = icon({
  iconRetinaUrl,
  iconUrl,
  shadowUrl,
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  tooltipAnchor: [16, -28],
  shadowSize: [41, 41],
});
```

And in another file, I added the required declarations so `TypeScript` allows me to import `png` images, e.g.

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

Also notice that, in case you use a Leaflet plugin that requires access to these images, you may need to explicitly assign it too, e.g. the Leaflet draw plugin required it as well. Example:

```
        map.addLayer(drawLayer);
        const drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
          draw: {
            circle: false,
            circlemarker: false,
            marker: {
              icon: Marker.prototype.options.icon, // Assign icon explicitly
            },
          },
          edit: {
            featureGroup: drawLayer,
          },
        });
        map.addControl(drawControl);
        map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, event => {
          const layer = (event as LayerEvent).layer;
          drawLayer.addLayer(layer);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to update your index.html with leaflet css

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBdNfgdfTC5n17Xddt2atTPudf34rdf45erfggrrddfdffdfEdf1HxjVMSvLVW9odfdfcdfdf3rfddfdferdfdfqdfgdfUKLsCC5gdfdfdCXdbqCmblFFAshOdfdfMAS6/kddderfdfeqq/sMZMZ19scRerdfggdfddffd4PsZChyertfgRRRSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

Put the css in header

Answer (score 1):

The most portable solution (and well suited for Rails 7) is:

In your Javascript controller, put this before the usual Leaflet map config code:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

import L from "leaflet";    
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {

    L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
      iconRetinaUrl: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
      iconUrl:       'data:image/png;base64,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',
      shadowUrl:     'data:image/png;base64,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'
    });


...
... // [Put the rest of the usual Leaflet map config code here]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

@GilEpshtain 's answer worked for me on Angular 9.1.9.

Additional note - for debugging purposes, you should be able to confirm that the change to `angular.json#assets` specified by @GilEpshtain has taken effect, by putting one of the icon URLs directly into your browser.    For instance `http://localhost:4200/assets/marker-icon.png` should show you the marker icon.

Answer (score 0):

Using Astro (or any vanilla JS project), since most folks need to use a custom marker anyway, it makes sense to link directly to the file you need.

```html
<script>

  // leaflet code...

  // link directly to the files
  const markerIcon = L.icon({
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [10, 41],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40],
    iconRetinaUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png',
    iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png',
    shadowUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png',
  })
  
  // use with marker
  let marker = L.marker([items[i].lat, items[i].lng], { icon: markerIcon })
        .addTo(map)
        .bindPopup(returnPopupHtml(items[i]))

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try upgrading to current version of leaflet- I have never encountered this problem with the marker icons.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.2/leaflet.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.2/leaflet.js
```