# How to correctly import leaflet in jhipster app, running webpack? - marker-icon missing

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, leaflet, jhipster

I am trying to implement an **OpenStreetMap** via **Leaflet** in my **JHipster** application and use the locally installed leaflet files. Using the link to `leaflet.css` and `leaflet.js` online files works fine. Installing leaflet as **node_module** and importing leaflet into my application is faulty. I am using maven for my application and trying to reproduce the example from Leaflet [homepage](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/).

### This approach works:

Simply including the following lines in the head section of my index.html works fine. (This is explained in the tutorial on Leaflet [homepage](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/).)
`index.html`

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@latest/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="crossorigin=""></script>
...
</head>
```

### This approach doesn't work:

Installing the leaflet `node_module` via `npm` like:

```
npm install --save --save-exact leaflet
npm install --save-dev --save-exact @types/leaflet
```

and subsequently, include the locally installed module in the head section of my `index.html` file

```
<head>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

does not work at all. No map is displayed. Why is that not straight forward as with the link to online files?

### This approach is incomplete:

Following the `README` from Jhipster and installing the leaflet `node_module` via `npm` like:

```
npm install --save --save-exact leaflet
npm install --save-dev --save-exact @types/leaflet
```

then adding following lines to import `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css`. In `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts` adding:

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.js';
```

and in `src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css` adding:

```
@import '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

This will display me the map **BUT** the marker icon is displayed as a broken image. In `README` they say that there are still a few steps to do but I can not find anything about those steps. Can anyone tell what needs to be done additionally?

Comment: The issue is probably how webpack build handles images and how they can bee linked from CSS.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411497/leaflet-marker-not-found-production-env-angular-7/56411961?r=SearchResults#56411961

Comment: many thanks @ghybs ! exactly what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is known for combining leaflet with webpack, see [Leaflet issue #4698](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968).

**Here is the configuration that solves it for me:**

Following the `README` from Jhipster and installing the leaflet `node_module` via `npm` like:

```
npm install --save --save-exact leaflet
npm install --save-dev --save-exact @types/leaflet
```

then adding following lines to import `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css`, and to explicitly specify the default icon images resource. In `src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts` adding:

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.js';
declare let L;
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
  iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
  iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
  shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});
```

and in `src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css` adding:

```
@import '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```